# shape in android

Tags: android

After long study from [Best way to handle shape drawable differences Android 2.3.5 vs 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547586/best-way-to-handle-shape-drawable-differences-android-2-3-5-vs-4-0) , [Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-mdpi, Drawable-ldpi Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263265/drawable-hdpi-drawable-mdpi-drawable-ldpi-android) , And [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533410/drawable-folders-in-res-folder) and [this best tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) I have started to do sample application.

I have stored the following shape in `res/drawable-ldpi`

```
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

<gradient
    android:angle="225"
    android:endColor="#ffa500"
    android:startColor="#DD000000" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:radius="0.1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
```

and the following in `res/drawable-hdpi`,`res/drawable-mdpi`,`res/drawable-xhdpi`,`res/drawable-v14`

```
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

<gradient
    android:angle="225"
    android:endColor="#ffa500"
    android:startColor="#DD000000" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:radius="0.1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
```

it looks like this in all type of emulators . that is in hvga , qvga , version 4.0.3 and samsung duos 
[image]

but in micromax funbook why it looks like this.

[image]

what's the problem here. Is there anything else I want to do. Help me friends.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the first one into `res/drawable`

and the second in `res/drawable-v14`

remove the others from `res/drawable-ldpi`, `res/drawable-hdpi`, `res/drawable-mdpi`, `res/drawable-xhdpi`

**[Update]**

Why to remove from other res/drawable-XXX folder:
Android always takes the best drawable for the device. as you just need other versions for android < 4.0 and >= 4.0 you only need this two directories

[Android Developer Docu on this Topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Comment: can you explain me little bit more why i cant have that in specific folders friend.

Comment: you can have, but you dont need. :) android always takes the best drawable for the device. as you just need other versions for android < 4.0 and >= 4.0 you only need this two directories

Comment: @ClassStacker the problem is, that there seems to be a bug in android, having the correct XML resulting in wrong shape. (at least that is how i understand this question and the question he [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547586/best-way-to-handle-shape-drawable-differences-android-2-3-5-vs-4-0)). If this issue is real (i didn't test it) then the solution i provided should work exactly how he wanted it.

Comment: and i bet, if my solution would not work for him, he had not accepted it

Comment: i just edited/updated the answer. feel free to remove the downvote